# How to wait for finish dataTaskWithRequest?

Tags: ios, asynchronous, nsurlsession

How can I wait for finish of `dataTaskWithRequest` ? I need to perform some tasks after network fetch is completely over.

Answer (score 7):

If you really need **synchronous** request, you can use **semaphores**.

I've implemented a small category on `NSURLSession` to provide this functionality.

In **.h** file:

```
@import Foundation.NSURLSession;

@interface NSURLSession (Additions)

+ (NSData *)sendSynchronousRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request returningResponse:(NSURLResponse **)response error:(NSError **)error;

@end
```

In **.m** file:

```
@implementation NSURLSession (Additions)

+ (NSData *)sendSynchronousRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request returningResponse:(NSURLResponse *__autoreleasing *)responsePointer error:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)errorPointer
{
    dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore;
    __block NSData *result = nil;

    semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

    void (^completionHandler)(NSData * __nullable data, NSURLResponse * __nullable response, NSError * __nullable error);
    completionHandler = ^(NSData * __nullable data, NSURLResponse * __nullable response, NSError * __nullable error)
    {
        if ( errorPointer != NULL )
        {
            *errorPointer = error;
        }

        if ( responsePointer != NULL )
        {
            *responsePointer = response;
        }

        if ( error == nil )
        {
            result = data;
        }

        dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
    };

    [[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:completionHandler] resume];

    dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

    return result;
}

@end
```

Comment: Sadly, this is crashing on  *errorPointer = error; and I can not use it.

Comment: @AlexZavatone can you please show how you call this method? Exactly how you declare the pointer for error

Answer (score 3):

I think, that method is obvious inside the class

```
NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [defaultSession dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                               completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error)
{
    // code after completion of task
}];
[task resume];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void) loginRequest:(NSString*) username withPassword:(NSString *) password callback:(void (^)(NSError *error, BOOL success))callback
{
    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [self.session dataTaskWithRequest:request 
                                                     completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error){
        if (error) {
            // Handle error, optionally using
            callback(error, NO);
        }
        else {
            callback(nil, YES);
        }
    }];

    [dataTask resume];
}
```

Call this method like so:

```
[self loginRequest:@"myUsername" password:@"password" callback:^(NSError *error, BOOL success) {
    if (success) {
        NSLog(@"My response back from the server after an unknown amount of time");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

lets just do your tasks in the completion block of dataTaskWithRequest.
Until than you can display an activity indicator to block the user from touching anything on the screen.

Example:

```
activityIndicator.startAnimating()

let task : NSURLSessionDataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
   activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
  // do your stuff here

});
```